# Java, Lambda: How to find a List from a Collection of Lists with different Types?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, prediction

Which is the best way in Java 8 to get a List with elements of `Type1` from a List of Lists -> (Records) `{List<Type1>, List<Type2>, List<Type3>, ...}` ?

Records has several Lists with different Types -> `{List<Type1>, List<Type2>, List<Type3>, ...}`

```
List<T> getList(T t) {
  // t is instance of Type1
  return Records -> List<t>;
}
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: are Type1, Type2 etc related?

Comment: No, the Types are fully independent from each other. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Utils<T> {

    List<T> getList(T t, List<List> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(i -> t.getClass().isInstance(i.get(0))).flatMap(List<T>::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```