# Java, Lambda: How to pick a List from a Class with several Lists of different Types?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, prediction

Which is the best way in Java 8 to pick&collect `Lists<T>` from a List of Objects (Records) which has several Lists with different Types `{List<Type1>, List<Type2>, List<Type3>, ..}`?

Type1, Type2, Type3 etc. are not related to each other.
T = Type1, Type2, Type3 ...

```
List<Records> allRecords;

class Records {
    List<Type1> listOfType1; // can be empty or null
    List<Type2> listOfType2; // can be empty or null
    List<Type3> listOfType3; // can be empty or null
}

List<T> getAllOccurrencesForType(T t, List<Records> allRecords) {
    return ?all occurrences of List<t> from all Records collected to one List? 
}
```

Comment: If your code is like that there is exactly one occurence of each type and you can use record.getListOfType1(). Maybe you add these lists dynamically to the records class?

Comment: What is the difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894007/java-lambda-how-to-find-a-list-from-a-collection-of-lists-with-different-types ?

Comment: I agree with @luk2302 - it looks like you are asking the same thing again. Maybe I am wrong - but then please explain why this second question is required and where it is different from what you asked before?!

Comment: Veselin Davidov, thanks for you comment. The list can have several Records and each Records has one List for each type.

Comment: `@luk2302`, `@GhostCat`: Thanks for your hint. I will check this ASAP. I asked a colleague of mine yesterday to try to find a solution for this task and he worked on my PC, while I was in meeting. I assume he used my account to post the same question. If so, I will flag this one as duplicated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe passing a getter `Function` that returns the required `List` can work:

```
static <T> List<T> getAllOccurrencesForType(Function<Records,List<T>> getter, List<Records> allRecords) {
    return allRecords.stream()
                     .flatMap(r->getter.apply(r).stream())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then you call it with:

```
List<Type1> getAllOccurrencesForType (Records::getListOfType1,allRecords);
```

Here's a full example:

```
class Records {
    List<String> listOfType1;
    List<Integer> listOfType2;
    List<Double> listOfType3;
    public Records (List<String> l1, List<Integer> l2, List<Double> l3) {
      listOfType1 = l1;
      listOfType2 = l2;
      listOfType3 = l3;
    }
    public List<String> getListOfType1() {
      return listOfType1;
    }
    public List<Integer> getListOfType2(){
      return listOfType2;
    }
    public List<Double> getListOfType3(){
      return listOfType3;
    }
}
```

Some `main` method:

```
 List<Records> recs = new ArrayList<> ();
 recs.add (new Records (Arrays.asList ("a","b"), Arrays.asList (1,2), Arrays.asList (1.1,4.4)));
 recs.add (new Records (Arrays.asList ("c","d"), Arrays.asList (4,3), Arrays.asList (-3.3,135.3)));
 List<String> allStrings = getAllOccurrencesForType(Records::getListOfType1,recs);
 List<Integer> allIntegers = getAllOccurrencesForType(Records::getListOfType2,recs);
 List<Double> allDoubles = getAllOccurrencesForType(Records::getListOfType3,recs);
 System.out.println (allStrings);
 System.out.println (allIntegers);
 System.out.println (allDoubles);
```

output:

```
[a, b, c, d]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1.1, 4.4, -3.3, 135.3]
```

Comment: Hi Eran, great answer, thanks  a lot :-)

I get the following compile error because of `r->getter.apply(r)` from the method `getAllOccurrencesForType()`!
`Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`

Comment: @ThomasMuller The code I posted passes compilation and runs on Eclipse Neon. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eran, I'm using eclipse Oxygen, Java EE IDE for Web Developers

Comment: @ThomasMuller Are you sure that you are using the exact code as in my answer? I find that Java 8 Error messages are often misleading. A simple typo can give you an error message that won't help you find it.

Comment: `@Eran`: Thanks for your time.
I placed your method into the following class:

`public class Utility<T> {
    static <T> List<T> getAllOccurrencesForType(Function<Records,List<T>> getter, List<Records> allRecords) {
        return allRecords.stream().flatMap(r->getter.apply(r).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}`

Comment: @ThomasMuller Can you try removing `<T>` from `Utility<T>`? It's already defined in the static method.

Comment: `@Eran`, I removed `<T>` from `Utility<T>`, but the exception is still there!!
Would it be possible please to send me your classes in the chat?
I will try it with those classes immediately.

Comment: @ThomasMuller All the relevant code is in my answer. Try to use my `Records` class from the answer and put the rest of the code (bottom 9 lines) in the `main` method of some class. The `getAllOccurrencesForType` method is in the same class as the `main`.

Comment: `@Eran`, okay thanks so much. I'll try it!

Comment: `@Eran`, Maybe I facing the same issue with Java 8, like described in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016329/cannot-use-java-8-method-with-lambda-arguments-without-specifying-type-arguments